# How do I provide a username and password to wget?

Tags: wget

I've tried to connect to a server via wget:

```
wget http://<user>:<pass>@serveradress
```

But wget responds: invalid port

I know that the server accepts incoming traffic at port 80.
How can I fix this issue?

Comment: I don't think you can reliably use the user:pass@name syntax there; `wget` has separate command line options for those instead, so is probably naively parsing the string after the `:` as a port number.

Comment: This has been already answered to be able to download protected one drive link.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62634214/how-to-download-protected-files-from-onedrive-using-wget/65862461#65862461

Answer (score 348, accepted):

Wget interprets `<pass>@serveraddress` as port. To specify a username and password, use the `--user` and `--password` switches:

```
wget --user user --password pass http://example.com/
```

From [`man wget`](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html):

> `--user=user`
>
> `--password=password`
>
> Specify the username *user* and password *password* for both FTP and HTTP file retrieval. These parameters can be overridden using the
>   `--ftp-user` and `--ftp-password` options for FTP connections and the `--http-user` and `--http-password` options for HTTP connections.

Comment: I prefer the `--ask-password` option described by Nabil Kadimi's answer. It has you enter the password invisibly on another line and avoids storing it in your shell history.

Comment: @Kevin You can avoid storing it in the shell history by starting the line with at least one space (as shown by [Nabil](http://askubuntu.com/a/399927/6969)). If the password/resource is sensitive, then you should worry more about the unencrypted HTTP/FTP/whatever connection than storing it on your disk.

Comment: I agree to the unencrypted password issue being more important in some cases than the shell history, but the answer is also useful for secure protocols. Also, sometimes you DO have to worry more about spies that have access to your computer than online spies (that are not interested by the content you're accessing or for which you don't care). The --ask-password answer below is clearly better for interactive usage, while the --password answer here is easier for automation. The comment by Ixgr about .wgetrc and chmod is also interesting in some cases.

Comment: As I understand the manual, pass is not interpreted as port.
"You can also encode your username and password within a URL: `http://user:password@host/path`"
" - [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#URL-Format)

Comment: Beyond shell history command line arguments are viewable by _ps_.

Answer (score 182):

You have 3 options here. They are in no specific order other than gut feeling:

#### 1. Password is visible to anyone (using the command `history`)

```
wget --user=remote_user --password=SECRET ftp://ftp.example.com/file.ext
```

The password will also be visible in `ps`, `top`, `htop` and similar.

#### 2. Password is visible to anyone looking behind your shoulders

```
 wget --user=remote_user --password=SECRET ftp://ftp.example.com/file.ext
```

Notice the white space before the command, it prevents saving it to your history.

The password will also be visible in `ps`, `top`, `htop` and similar. (Thanks [user412812](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29079/how-do-i-provide-a-username-and-password-to-wget/399927#comment890614_399927))

#### 3. Password is not visible to anyone including you

```
wget --user=remote_user --ask-password ftp://ftp.example.com/file.ext
```

Then you're asked for the password

```
Password for user `remote_user':
```

Comment: While it is not visible in history, it is visible to all who conduct a ps, top, htop or similar command while the process is running.

Comment: If `--ask-password` is not available or you don't want to type the password every time, `wget -i link.txt` can help, where `link.txt` contains `ftp://remote_user:SECRET@ftp.example.com/file.ext`

Answer (score 14):

You can also store the username and password in the file `~/.wgetrc`
and change the permissions of that file so that only your user can 
read it:

File `~/.wgetrc`:

```
user=john
password=SEcrEt
```

... and then

```
chmod 600 ~/.wgetrc
```

Note, however, that user `root` can still peek into that file and 
read the password.

From the [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/wget.1.html):

> To prevent the passwords from being seen,  use the `--use-askpass` or
>   store them in  `.wgetrc` or `.netrc`, and make sure to protect  those
>   files from other users with `"chmod"`.   If the passwords are really
>   important, do  not leave them lying in those files either --- edit 
>   the files and delete them after Wget has  started the download.

Answer (score 3):

This should work (don't miss the quotes)

```
wget 'http://<user>:<pass>@<serveradress>/<path>/<filename>'
```

Example for my access to the builds on ftp server

```
wget 'ftp://DOMAIN\thomas:dasbleibtgeheim@build.server12321.dd/download/bins/lastnightly_v1.2.3.bin'
```

Note: To avoid to get this in your shell history add a space in front of `wget` -->  `wget`

Answer (score 1):

You can provide authentication credential via `--user=USERNAME` and `--password=PASSWORD`; based on the `man wget`, the command can be overridden using the `--http-user=USERNAME` and `--http-password=PASSWORD` for *http* connection and the `--ftp-use=USERNAME` and `--ftp-password=PASSWORD` for *ftp* connection.

Answer (score -1):

The command could have used `--http-user` and `--http-password` instead of `--user` and `--password`. In case of `ftp` request the options are `--ftp-user` and `--ftp-password`.

Comment: This is not entirely correct:  `man wget` indicates that --user and --password are valid options, which *can be overridden* by --http-user or --ftp-password