# After giving username and password wget says wget: unrecognized option '--ask-password'

Tags: wget

i am very new to Ubuntu, I am using wget command to pass authentication details and download file from svn repository by adding its URL, but i am getting the error as "**wget: unrecognized option '--ask-password'**"

1. The command was: **wget --user="user_name" --ask-password URL**
2. Version(wget -V) of wget is **GNU wget 1.8.2**
3. when i did apt-get install wget it says:**wget is already the newest  version (1.17.1-1ubuntu1.4)**
4. There is confusion in version of wget and my Ubuntu version is **16.04**.

I searched lot many things i didn't get any proper solution please help me to solve the issue. Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. The 1.17.1-1ubuntu1.4 is the latest (https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/wget) for 16.04 LTS, but the 1.17.1-1* version number refers to package version (not program version).  Package version numbers are so your system can automatically upgrade packages, and have nothing to do with what's inside them.

Comment: OK Thank you  I understood , but what would be the reason for error i am getting

Comment: You'll have to wait for someone else with experience in that option  (If I knew it, I would have said), or possibly look at https://askubuntu.com/questions/29079/how-do-i-provide-a-username-and-password-to-wget  (how do i provide a username and password to wget; specifically the 81 upvote answer)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I provide a username and password to wget?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29079/how-do-i-provide-a-username-and-password-to-wget)

Comment: Please add the output of `which wget` and what version you get with `/usr/bin/wget -V`. Seems your system uses a wrong `wget` ?!

Comment: which wget gives  /usr/bin/wget    and                                             /usr/bin/wget -V gives GNU Wget 1.8.2

Copyright (C) 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 2000, 2001 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
GNU General Public License for more details.

Originally written by Hrvoje Niksic <hniksic@arsdigita.com>.

Answer (score 3):

`--ask-password` is a relatively old option. Introduced in 2012 with version 1.12.

However, the version of Wget you're using is even older, heck, its ancient. v1.8.2 of Wget was released in 2002! 16 years ago. You really need to update your version of Wget to something newer. There have been multiple vulnerabilities that have been fixed since then not to mention the various number of new features added.

I don't know much about Ubuntu, but I guess 16.04 is a LTS release which is currently supported. Which means its repositories should support something a lot newer. You should look into why your repositories are pointing only to such an old version of Wget

Comment: Consider to add links to actual [man-pages of wget](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/wget.1.html).

Comment: I don't see how a link to the Wget man page is relevant here, unless you link to both the current and the page for 1.8.

Answer (score 0):

After uninstalling wget and reinstalling it I got newer version. It works fine. I am able to download the file that I needed by passing authentication details. I did:

```
sudo apt purge --auto-remove wget
sudo apt install wget
```

Comment: The same could be achieved in a single Apt command: `sudo apt-get install -t "$(lsb_release -sc)" --reinstall wget`.